# How to create a time bomb in Github actions that runs Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions, cicd, time-bomb

I have recently encountered an issue that I will need to address in the future. As a result, I am interested to create a time bomb in my CI workflow:

> In computer software, a time bomb is part of a computer program that has been written so that it will start or stop functioning after a predetermined date or time is reached.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```yaml
jobs:
  Test-Runner:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      # Other steps ...
      - name: 'A timebomb to address an issue on the 01/05/2023'
        run: |
          if [[ $(date +%s) -gt 1682895600 ]]; then
            echo "It has been X months since #ISSUE was opened."
            echo "Please check if Y has been fixed."
            echo "  If it has, please update do Z."
            echo "  else, please increase this timebomb by 1 month."
            echo "See: ..."
          fi
```

I want this step to fail **on the given date**, is this possible using Github actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub actions respect Linux exit codes, and set them to the action's check run status, which can be 'success' or 'failure'.

From the documentation, [Setting exit codes for actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/setting-exit-codes-for-actions):

> You can use exit codes to set the status of an action. GitHub displays statuses to indicate passing or failing actions.

Like usual, `0` indicates success, and:

> Any other exit code indicates the action failed. When an action fails, all concurrent actions are canceled and future actions are skipped. The check run and check suite both get a failure status.

Therefore doing something as simple as checking the current date and returning a non-zero exit code:

```yaml
jobs:
  Test-Runner:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      # Other steps ...
      - name: 'A timebomb to address an issue on the 01/05/2023'
        run: |
          if [[ $(date +%s) -gt 1682895600 ]]; then
            echo "It has been X months since #ISSUE was opened."
            echo "Please check if Y has been fixed."
            echo "  If it has, please update do Z."
            echo "  else, please increase this timebomb by 1 month."
            echo "See: ..."
            exit 1 # <--- A non-zero exit code 
          fi
      - name: 'Uploading test artifacts'
        if: success() || failure()
```

Will fail the CI on a given date. It is important note you will need to **place this at the end of your test steps** if you want other steps to run before failing the job. (perhaps just before uploading your test artifacts)